# Is there a way to update array value in algolia Partial Update Method?

Tags: algolia

My records are something like this,

```
{
    objectID: "123123",
    product_id: "456456",
    categories: ['pie', 'desert']
}
```

I want to just replace `desert` with `sweet` in categories.

Is this possible by using `partial_update_objects` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a value but ultimately you can `Remove` & `Add` with the [built-in operations](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/partial-update-objects/#built-in-operations). It would allow an "update" of the value (it only works if the values in the array are unique). An alternative is to get the object and compute the new value for the array to later replace it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Since my array values may not be unique I'll replace the whole array attribute.